# Problem accessing wp-load.php

Tags: wp-load.php

I'm writing a standalone script for Wordpress so I can display things like the username on a page outside of Wordpress.

My method so far is to try to include or require wp-load.php in my script directory.  I've tried

```
chdir ( ".." );
include "wp-load.php";
```

as well as absolute paths to the web root where Wordpress is located for both the chdir and the include.  I don't get any errors but wp_get_current_user() always returns empty.

If I move my script up a level to the same folder with Wordpress it works fine.  How can I include wp-load.php and keep all of the files in my subfolder?

EDIT: file structure

- public_html (wordpress is installed here so wp-load.php is also here)

  - myScript (directory)

    - script.php
    - This is where I try to use chdir ( ".." ) or include ( "../wp-load.php" ) without success

Comment: and please tell me the where you exactly include the wp-load.php

Comment: did you got the result @scottinthebooth ?

Comment: I was not able to get this to work.  I ended up just converting the script to a full plugin which solved the problem (if I'd realized how simple that was I would have started that way)

Answer (score 1):

try this i hope this work.

```
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );    
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: This did not work.  My script is in a folder "next to" wordpress, not being served by wordpress itself so I'm not inside the wp-content folder

Comment: please put here you folder hierarchy

Comment: I edited the original post to include it

Comment: http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/   please read it carefully. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this to include

```
<?php include '../wp-load.php'; ?>
```

that will give you the wp-load.php file `../` is usually use for get path of last folder.

hope this helps you and also let me know the result.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work. I ended up just converting the script to a full plugin which solved the problem (if I'd realized how simple that was I would have started that way)